# Error loading from Database. User is not associated with trusted SQL Server Connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication

I have a C# WPF-Application that tries to connect so SQL Server Express 2008.
Connection-String is:

> "Data Source=10.10.10.1\SQLEXPRESS,49170;Database=Pflanzenverwaltung;User Id=...;Password=...;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"

I did the following:

- Enabled Mixed Mode Authentication (SQL Server Auth AND Windows Auth) (checked in registry as well)
- Added User to "SQL Server Connection -> Security -> Logins" (Assigned Server Roles "public" and "sysadmin"
- Added User to Database-> Security -> Users (It's possible to Login to this Connection using The Login)
- Restarted SQLServer

When I start my WPF-Application the following error is shown:
"Error loading from Database. Error Signing in for the user .... User is not associated to a trusted SQL Server-Connection"
 - 
In "SQL Server Log" there are no entries containing the username but in "SQL Server- and Windows-Protocol" it says: "User is not associated to a trusted SQL Server Connection"

Comment: What is the code that runs at startup? Are you sure it is using that connection string?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I get the connection string from App.config and the user mentioned in the error message is the one from connection string.

Comment: The user doesn't matter if the credentials are in the connection string. I ask because you should not get a Windows authentication ("trusted connection") error if you are using SQL auth.

Comment: Disable Windows authentication in connection string "Persist Security Info=False"

Comment: @DenisRubashkin if that is the complete connection string then windows auth is not used.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin I added this but it doesnt change anything

Comment: @Crowcoder, Windows Authentication is preferred for connecting to SQL Server so if it isn't disabled explicitly, Login Id and Password will be ignored and the windows auth will be used.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin that is false. To use windows auth you omit user and password and you use "Integrated Security" instead. Persist Security Info has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @uwieuwe4 Debug at the point of opening the connection and look at the runtime value of the connection string.

Comment: Another option is that Mixed mode is NOT enabled, even if the OP states it

Comment: @Crowcoder I did and it its the same string I wrote in the question

Comment: >>>Data Source=10.10.10.1\SQLEXPRESS,49170;<<< You should not indicate BOTH Server instance name and the port, in this case the port only will be considered. So if there is ANOTHER instance that listens on 49170, you may connect to ANOTHER instance that you may think

Comment: @sepupic I checked it in registry (Login-Mode = 2). Is there another way to check it?

Comment: @sepupic I have only one instance of sql server running on the machine

Comment: is it local machine?

Comment: Another way to check the port and Authentication mode is to read server's errorlog

Comment: @sepupic no its a remote server but in the same network.

Comment: Could you please update your question with some of the first rows of SQL SERVER error log?

Comment: If you can reach that pc using RDP, please check server's error log

Comment: In one of the first rows of error log (6th row in my case) there is written smth like this: Authentication mode is MIXED.

Comment: If you could check the registry of that pc I think you can also check server's error log

Comment: Sorry for a dumb question, but we can't see your code so.... did you make sure the SqlCommand is assigned the SqlConnection associated with that connection string? Sometimes its a palm-to-face issue.

Comment: @sepupic i checked the error log and it says Authentication Mode is MIXED. I am going to update the question in a second

Comment: @Crowcoder yes I did. Thank you. On my private computer the code is working well